# java Loose Coupling avoid using implemnetation types like 'ArrayList'; Use the interface instead

Tags: java, arraylist, loose-coupling

WE have this app for coding standards called Sonar.  I have this one function that returns an ArrayList and sonar is says "java Loose Coupling avoid using implemnetation types like 'ArrayList'; Use the interface instead"

For example if i do this, sonar gives that error.

```
    public ArrayList<String> test()
       {
       ArrayList<String> testing = new ArrayList<String>();
        return testing;
        }
```

I  am not sure how to correct the sonar message to use an interface instead.

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return a `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>` :

```
public List<String> test()
{
    List<String> testing = new ArrayList<String>();
    return testing;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that users of the `test()` method won't have to know which implementation of `List<String>` you are actually using, and you'll be able to switch to a different implementation without changing the API of your method.